# IRS e-file Error Messaging

Tags: united-states, income-tax, irs, electronic-filing

The following is the error code sent back saying they were unable to process my return due to these error:

"Taxpayer TIN in the Return Header must not be the same as a TIN of a previously accepted electronic return for the return type and tax period indicated in the tax return."

I am not sure how to correct the "error". I have checked filing "head of household" with 1 dependent. My primary birthdate and SSN are correct. My e-filed return was originally rejected because I did not reference my spouse's name & SSN since she is / was filing separately.  Her return was rejected for the same reason.  The corrections were made and the returns re-submitted.  Hers has now been successfully processed but I received the error notice above.

Comment: You mention head of household, but then mention your spouse. Do you live apart?

Comment: Either you and your spouse are considered married under IRS rules or you aren't. If you are, then you can't file as head of household. If you aren't, then you shouldn't reference your spouse's name and SSN since you're not considered married.

Comment: Could it be you **already filed it** ?  the systyem is trying to file it again?

Answer (score 1):

If any of the SSN/ITIN's on your tax return were included on another persons tax return it can render you unable to e-file. A common scenario is when a dependent is claimed by both parents separately, the first to file can e-file and the 2nd to file will have to paper file if they want to claim the dependent. Typically these paper-filed returns get processed normally and then later in the year you'll both get a follow-up from the IRS and have to sort out which parent has to amend to remove the dependent.

Even if your spouse did not claim your child as a dependent, e-filing may just not be an option due to some glitch or a separate fraudulent return having been filed. The resolution is the same, paper file your return and await any notice from the IRS to sort things out later.